# ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE only in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a D-Link web camera running on port 8080 (router is configured to forward outside traffic to that port to web camera). If I try with Firefox or Internet Explorer, everything works fine. It asks for username/password and opens the web cameras' console.

But when I try with Chrome (latest version of course), I get `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`. Why?

I tried with CURL to check and I get below error:

> HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required
>   Server: alphapd
>   Date: Wed Feb 21 05:18:53 2018
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Content-type: text/html
>   Content-length: 103
>   WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="DCS-932L_7B"
>
> ### Error: Authorization Required
>
> Authentication was requested

It looks like Chrome doesn't open login mask. But why?

Comment: The current version of Chrome, if I am not mistaken, treats all HTTP connections are insecure.  So unless this camera supports HTTPS it might be connected.

Comment: If you use the previous version of Chrome does it work?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried on two computers with older (different) version of Chrome, but I got the same error. It is interesting that the same behavior is on Android. It works on Firefox but doesn't on Chrome (same error).